# Assigning returned value in a match arm to a new variable

Tags: rust

I am working on my first Rust project, a CLI application to find large files on a local filesystem. Rust has excellent [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-02-match.html) regarding match statements but I do not see how I can assign a value returned by the function passed to the match statement in a new variable:

```
pub fn run(config: Config) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let mut results_map: Option<Results>;
    match search(&config.root_path) {
        Err(e) => eprintln!("Error when calling run(): {:?}", e),
        Ok(results) => results_map = results), // how to properly assign value returned by function here?
    }

    Ok(())
}

pub struct Results {
    result_map: HashMap<String, u64>,
}

pub fn search(path: &str) -> Result<Results, io::Error> {
    let root_path = Path::new(path);
    let mut results = Results { result_map: HashMap::<String, u64>::new()};


    match visit_dirs(root_path, &mut results) {
        Err(e) => eprintln!("Error calling visit_dirs() from search(): {:?}", e),
        _ => (),
    }

    Ok(results)
}
```

Comment: You must pattern match the result. Currently you match it with `_` (dont care). Since you care about the result you should match with an expression `Ok(result)` instead. As [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=68fe11299cb3c091ec6c4c9a30042a4e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions you're calling in the match statements, `search` and `visit_dirs` return `Result` types. You have to use one of the arms of the `match` statement to cover the `Ok` (happy) case, next to where you're already covering the `Err` (error) case:

```
match search(&config.root_path) {
    Ok(results) => return results,
    Err(e) => eprintln!("Error when calling run(): {:?}", e),       
}
```

Or you can assign the result of the `match` expression to a new variable:

```
let new_variable = match search(&config.root_path) {
    Ok(results) => results, // no return here
    Err(e) => {
       eprintln!("Error when calling run(): {:?}", e)
       // Either choose to panic (not recommended)
       // panic!("Bad times lie ahead")
       // Or propagate the error from your own Result
       return Err(e);
    },       
}
```

You may want to look into the [`?` operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std/result/question_mark.html) to simplify this in the common case.

Comment: Thanks for such a well explained solution.  I've used the `?` operator in other functions that return the unit type, but I am not sure how to use it in the context of assigning whatever value is contained in `Ok()` to a new variable.  Can you explain?

Comment: @JohnHarrington For instance if your function returned the same error type as the function you're calling (or a supertype of it), you could simply do `let new_variable = search(&config.root_path)?;` and it would handle the early return (though not the printing obviously) for you and there would be no need for a match arm.